# spring mongodb criteria API: check two values on the same nested element

Tags: spring, mongodb, criteria-api

I have the following query:

```
Criteria crit = Criteria.where("nestedObj.date").lt(LocalDate.now())
        .and("nestedObj.active").is(true)
        .and("someId").is(null)
        .and("somethingElse").exists(false);
```

How can I make sure that `nestedObj.active` and `nestedObj.date` are checked on the same `nestedObj`?

I only want this to match if a document has a `nestedObj` that is active AND has a date older than today.

Example:

If the `nestedObj` array on a document loos like this, the query should match:

```
[
    {
    "nestedObj": {
        "active": "true",
        "date": "2010-29-10"
    },
    {
    "nestedObj": {
        "active": "false",
        "date": "2010-29-10"
    },
    {
    "nestedObj": {
        "active": "true",
        "date": "2022-29-10"
    }
]
```

But if it looks like this, it shouldn't:

```
[
    {
    "nestedObj": {
        "active": "false",
        "date": "2010-29-10"
    },
    {
    "nestedObj": {
        "active": "true",
        "date": "2022-29-10"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the element match in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

for instance

`where("nestedObj.date").elemMatch(               where("attribute1").`is`("value1").and("attribute2").regex("(?i).*$something.*")`